# Layout in html to print using QPainter

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui

How can I use QPainter to access my layout in html?

example layout html for print:

```
QString address= "Example address";
QString html_layout_print;
html_layout_print = "<div align="center">Layout html for print</div>"
                    "<div align="center">"+address+"</div>";

QPainter // << get html to print
```

I'm having trouble creating a layout for print, with painter.drawText () command.

Code:

```
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
printer.setPageMargins(5,5,5,5,QPrinter::Millimeter);
QPainter painter(&printer);
painter.drawText(10, 10, QString("Header %1").arg("Header example"));
```

---

**New code, QTextDocument:**

```
  QString text_x = "Hello World!";
   QTextDocument *doc = new QTextDocument(this);
   doc->setUndoRedoEnabled(false);
   doc->setHtml("<p><span style=\"color:#000000; font-weight:600\">"+text_x+"</span></p>");
   doc->setTextWidth(width());
   doc->setUseDesignMetrics(true);
   doc->setDefaultTextOption(QTextOption(Qt::AlignHCenter));

   QPainter *p = new QPainter(this);
   p->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
   doc->drawContents(p);
   p->end();
```

Return erro:

```
QPainter::pen: Painter not active
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::pen: Painter not active
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::restore: Unbalanced save/restore
QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need more sophisticated HTML printing you should have a look into the QWebKit classes. Create a QWebPage object, supply your HTML and use a mainFrame()->render() call with your painter. This will give you an image that can be printed.

If you do not need an image but pure printing only, an alternative is a mainFrame()->print() call.

Comment: Could look at my code? is returning blank page. `QWebView *view = new QWebView(this);
    view->page()->mainFrame()->load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"));

    QPrinter printer;
    QPainter painter(&printer);
    view->page()->mainFrame()->render(&painter);
    painter.end();`

Comment: If you use a QWebView than first try view->load(); And why do you use both, a painter and a printer? Using the print() method you will not need a painter.

Comment: Could you please look at my new code? I am trying to print with `QtextDocument` but returns error: `QPainter::pen: Painter not active`  `QPainter::setPen: Painter not active`  Code in topic

Comment: Try QPainter::begin() and QPainter::end()